# CSS : Absolute like positioning w.r.t static element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like to create a `.cover` div like this

```
<div style="position:relative;">
   <div class="cover" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;"></div>
</div>
```

but which could achieve a similar cover effect even if the parent element in not a positioned element (static). In short what CSS styling would make a div completely cover its static positioned parent without affecting the flow of the rest of it's siblings / children ?

Comment: What is the issue with using `position:relative`? Especially since `z-index` requires positioning context.

Comment: this div should not interfere with the positions of its static siblings

Comment: It's still not clear what the issue is. Just adding `position:relative` **with no other values** should have no effect on siblings.

Comment: but I actually needed a div which can entirely cover its parent regardless of its parent's positioning property

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. It's not possible on the face of it..and just setting `position:relative` for the parent solves the problem. Why is this an issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m8b76Ls6/ this is the difference and I am trying to achieve the appearance of the first one when the parent is `static`

Comment: **Why** does the parent **need** to be static? Why can't the child be absolute exactly as you have in your quoted code in the question.?

Comment: absolute actually works if the parent is positioned that means will not work with static parent so that for more flexible usage

Comment: I **know** it won't work with static elements...my question is why are you avoiding setting the static elements to relative? You have the solution in front of you but you seem unwilling to use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59814/discussion-between-eldos-and-paulie-d).

Answer (score 1):

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7os8y2qv/). Are you trying to do an overlay like this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="bacon"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p></div>

<div class="chicken"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p></div>

<div class="cover"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cover {
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
background-color:#000;
opacity:0.8;
display:block;
z-index:1001; }
```

Comment: but I would like the `.cover` to cover only its parent element

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
style="height: inherit; width: inherit;"
```

`inherit` means get from the parent element. [Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp).

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem with `position` of the child w.r.t parent element